# Bash binding ctrl + alt modifiers

Tags: bash, keyboard-shortcuts, key-binding, xbindkeys

I am not being able to bind Ctrl+Alt+u in my bash.

I have followed [this link](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/48264/how-to-bind-ctrl-alt-b-as-the-prefix-of-tmux) but did not work for me.

I can bind it to Ctrl+u with:

```
bind '"\C-u"':"\"cd ..\C-m\""
```

and to Alt+u with:

```
bind '"\eu"':"\"cd ..\C-m\""
```

But it's impossible for me to bind both together.

I tried everything, `\C-\ew` not working, `\C-\M-u` not working... etc

Comment: Did you check what sequence of characters is sent, as suggested there? You can test with Ctrl-V followed by Ctrl-Alt-G. You may find that it's just `^G`.

Comment: @muru I tried it, but I am using windows linux subsystem. It shows its as you say, in capital letter, but did not work either :(

Comment: What I'm trying to say is, your shell is getting the equivalent of Ctrl-G, whether you type Ctrl-Alt-G or just Ctrl-G. The binding won't help even if you could make it.

Comment: @muru So you mean there is actually no way to distinguish between Ctrl+Alt+Key and Ctrl+Key in my terminal?

Comment: Not if you all get is `^G`.

Comment: Yes, that's what I get!! Thank you very much for your info :)